# Convert double and vertex handle into a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, cgal

I want to convert a vertex handle(vit) and double value to string and write it into a file.I thought this works.

```
string buffer = vit->point() + " " +z_co[vit->id] +"\n";
```

z_co:is a vector.(double) 
But,it is throwing error.So,How could I do this?

Comment: What are the types of `vit` and `z_co`? What is the error string? We need more information here.

Comment: When posting a question about build error, please provide the complete and unedited build log in the question. Plus all needed relevant code, like variable declarations and class/structure definitions.

Comment: vit->point() is not a string, nor does z_co[vit->id], right? So the operator+ is certainly not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append a `double` to string like that.

Instead use e.g. [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << vit->point() << " " << z_co[vit->id] << '\n';
std::string buffer = os.str();
```